How to set a dynamic cache duration for an auth handler on AWS API Gateway?
I have an auth handler lambda written in Python that returns a policy document. For certain users, I'd like to set a cache duration (300s), and for other users I'd like for it to not cache at all.
For reference, this is an HTTP API on gateway, not a REST API.
I have the default settings on the authorizer set to 300s and then for those I don't want to cache I've added policy["context"]["TTLOverride"] = 0. For some reason, the users that are getting this bit added are still having their policies caches for the full 300s.

Clarify if you are using a custom authorizer and how you are setting the policy document. Provide relevant code snippets.
